# Setting up WalletConnect

Tags: metamask, walletconnect

I'd like to implement WalletConnect on my site, so that users of a platform I'm trying to improve a lot (real estate tokenization) can connect their MetaMask wallet (and others eventually?!) to the site, so that we can display a portfolio with the tokens the person owns (ERC20).

Do you have any idea how to set this up? I can't easily find any documentation on this subject.

Thank you

Comment: Here is a good tutorial https://github.com/Web3Modal/web3modal-vanilla-js-example/

Answer (score 1):

Below is the sample code that demonstrate use of Etherjs with walletConnect's web3Modal library that provides multiple wallet options to allow users to connect to dApp using wallet of their choice.

```
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import Web3Modal from "web3modal";
import WalletConnectProvider from "@walletconnect/web3-provider";

    //defining supported provider
     const providerOptions = {
        injected: {
          display: {
            name: "MetaMask",
            description: "Connect with the metamask from your Browser",
          },
          package: null,
        },
        walletconnect: {
          display: {
            name: "WalletConnect",
            description: "Scan qrcode with your mobile wallet",
          },
          package: WalletConnectProvider,
          options: {
            rpc: {
              [CHAIN_ID]: RPC_URL,
            },
          },
        },
      };
        //creating web3 modal instance
        const web3Modal = new Web3Modal({
              cacheProvider: false, // optional
              providerOptions, // required
              });
        
        //invoking wallet modal 
        let instance = await web3Modal.connect();
        
        //creating etherjs instance from wallet connect
        let injectedInstance = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(instance);
        
        //creating a signer
        const signer = provider.getSigner();
        
        //creating contract instance and invoking contract function
        const contractInstance = new ethers.Contract(
                  CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
                  CONTRACT_ABI,
                  signer
                );
        let transactionHash = await contractInstance.functionName(param1,{value:gweiAmount});
```