# How can I let an user login to their Metamask wallet and return their public address on mobile?

Tags: web3js, metamask, javascript, ethereum-wallet-dapp

At the moment my website allows users to link their Metamask wallet by simply using the window.ethereum object that is attached to the window, assuming the metamask chrome extension is installed. Once a user's wallet is linked that way, I can simply get their public address back.

this is the code that lets me get a user's account:

```
const loginToWallet = async () => {
    if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {
        console.log('MetaMask is installed!');
        const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

After that I can just access the ethereum.selectedAddress and get their public address. However, this method does not work if users are coming from mobile.

I'm trying to find a solution or a js library that replicates the same flow that happens on PC on mobile.

I tried to look into Moralis but there is too much noise around the library, react components, databases, I couldn't find a clear way to do it without needing those things.

I think maybe the web3.js library could be a solution but I was wondering if someone could help me out finding what I'm looking for, I'm not very good at understanding library documentations.

Comment: Some projects use WalletConnect to interact with mobile wallets. See this question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/84325/setting-up-walletconnect.

Comment: @ismael God bless you that is exactly what I was looking for. I'd kiss you if I could. Have a nice day!